# É possível inflar uma classe em vez de layout utilizando o FragmentTab?

Tags: android

Eu fiz uma formulário dinâmico, então tenho que inflar a classe e não o layout, mas estou na dúvida se isso é possível com TabFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode inflar uma classe.  E também não pode por uma activity dentro de um fragmentTab.  O que você pode fazer é por em cada aba um fragment e controlar da classe que você usar para inflar o layout desse fragment.  Uma classe que de extends em fragment. Nessa classe você pode fazer tudo tão dinâmico quanto queira.